# sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 27

Tags: sudo, configuration

```
root@debian:/home/debian8# cat  /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

The 27th line is only removed a chracter #,the primitive format is as below.

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I just remove the # character.

```
root@debian:/home/debian8# ls  /etc/sudoers.d
myRules  README
root@debian:/home/debian8# cat  /etc/sudoers.d/myRules
debian8  ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` is not a comment, `#includedir` is a directive. The hash sign is part of it. Just re-add it.

Answer (score 2):

According to `man sudoers` one should use `@includedir`:

> Including other files from within sudoers  It is possible to include
> other sudoers files from within the sudoers file currently being
> parsed using the @include and @includedir directives.  For
> compatibility with sudo  versions prior to 1.9.1, #include and
> #includedir are also accepted.

> The @includedir directive can be used to create a sudoers.d directory
> that the system package manager can drop sudoers file rules into as
> part of package installation.  For ex‐ ample, given:
>
> @includedir /etc/sudoers.d
>
> sudo will suspend processing of the current file and read each file in
> /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’
> character to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor
> temporary/backup files.  Files are parsed in sorted lexical order.
> That is, /etc/sudoers.d/01_first will be parsed before
> /etc/sudoers.d/10_second.  Be aware that because the sorting is
> lexical, not numeric, /etc/sudoers.d/1_whoops would be loaded after
> /etc/sudoers.d/10_second.  Using a consistent number of leading zeroes
> in the file names can be used to avoid such problems.  After parsing
> the files in the directory, control returns to the file that contained
> the @includedir directive.
>
> Note that unlike files included via @include, visudo will not edit the
> files in a @includedir directory unless one of them contains a syntax
> error.  It is still possible to run visudo with the -f flag to edit
> the files directly, but this will not catch the redefinition of an
> alias that is also present in a different file.

Comment: You may want to mention what version of `sudo` this applies to as it seems to be a very recent change (not in `Sudo version 1.8.31` on Ubuntu Focal, for example).

Comment: I added the documentation excerpt talking about the version from which the change occurred.